# How to create a git repository to fetch another repo in every single push to original one?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is it possible to create a git repository to fetch every single change from original repository? We just push our changes to the original one and the mirror repo automatically fetch these changes. 
In other words, how it comes to possible to have two or more git repository which all of them get updated by just one push?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [repository mirroring](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html) feature gitlab provides.

The free version of Gitlab allows to push to a remote repository. You therefor have to add all the mirrors to the original project. See [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html#pushing-to-a-remote-repository-core) for the documentation.

In case you are using a paid version of gitlab (currently Starter/Bronze), you can add repository pulling. You add the original repo to the repo where to code should be cloned to. The documentation for this can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/repository_mirroring.html#pulling-from-a-remote-repository-starter).